# Reuse UniqueId in project 2010

Tags: ms-project, unique-id

I have a program in project 2010 with few tasks.

Each task has its own unique-id (i.e. it is being populated automatically into UniqueID column by the project).

For some reason, some of the tasks got deleted.

1. I want to use again UniqueID of those deleted tasks. Is it possible?
2. Is there a way to retrieve tasks that were deleted?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In short, the answer to both questions is no. More information:

1. You cannot reuse the UniqueID of a task that was deleted as the UniqueID is automatically generated. The only control the user has is to add and delete tasks to skip over UniqueIDs or to build a new schedule and painstakingly add the tasks in the correct order to mimic the UniqueIDs in the original schedule.
2. Yes, if you have a back-up copy of your schedule before you deleted the tasks. Otherwise, no.